# Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<string>' because it is not a delegate type

Tags: c#, generics, lambda

Method signature:

```
public static IDictionary<string, object> ListX(this object instance)
```

Code:

```
          if (instance == null)
                throw new NullReferenceException();

            var result = instance as IDictionary<string, object>;
            if (result != null)
                return result;
                return instance.GetType()
                    .GetProperties()
                    .ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x =>
                    {
  object value = x.GetValue(instance);
            if (value != null)
            {
                var valueType = value.GetType();

                // Whe should manually check for string type because IsPrimitive will return false in case of string
                if (valueType.IsPrimitive || valueType == typeof(string))
                {

                    return value;
                }
                // If the value type is enumerable then we iterate over and recursively call ToDictionary on each item
                else if (valueType.GetInterfaces().Any(t => t == typeof(IEnumerable)))
                {
                    List<object> elements = new List<object>();
                    foreach (var item in value as IEnumerable)
                    {
                        elements.Add(item.ToDictionary());
                    }
                    return elements;
                }
                // The value type is a complex type so we recursively call ToDictionary
                else
                {
                    return value.ToDictionary();
                }
            }
            return null;
                    });
```

For `x` I get `Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<string>' because it is not a delegate type`.

Whats the propblem here ?

Ok, I updated that code.

Comment: Is your actual code incomplete as well? If so, the lack of a return value is probably confusing the type inference between the two overloads of `ToDictionary` which take three parameters.

Comment: Also make sure to cast your return type to `object`, for example: `x => { return (object)x.PropertyType; }`

Comment: instead of `x=>{}` write `x =>GetValue(instance)`

Comment: `var pp = instance.GetType().GetProperties().ToDictionary(x=> x.Name, x=> {return (object)x.Name; });` works pretty well for me. @Lee is right, if your second lamda is missing the `return` statement, the compiler can't infer which overload to use.

Comment: The problem is that your second lamda doesn't return any value. The structure is `Action<PropertyInfo>` but `Func<PropertyInfo, object>` is expected. To make it compilable try `x => { return null; }`. To Return the current value try `x => x.GetValue(instance, null)` (but in that case try to add a where clause that removes all indexers). There is an overload of `ToDictionary` that takes an `IEqualityComparer<T>` and your lambda could not be converted into that.

Comment: updated my post, hope you can help

Comment: May be the problem is that `item` and `value` do not have a `ToDictionary()` ?

Comment: Recursively by using `ToDictionary`? Do you mean `ListX()` instead? Maybe [this](http://ideone.com/3LHI4O) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that ToDictionary expects an IEqualityComparer as the second parameter and what you providing does not implement that interface.

You got an explanation on how to use this metod in the following link: http://www.dotnetperls.com/todictionary

Comment: There is also an overload which expects two extraction expressions, one for the key, one for the value. This is obviously the one the op wants to use, but he does not implement it correctly, so the Compiler cannot infer the correct overload.